# C++: convert not from obj1 to obj2, but from obj1* to obj2?

Tags: c++11, type-conversion

A constructor for `MyClass` takes a pointer to another such object.

The C++ `MyClass` is functionally the same as a C "class" based on a typedef'd struct called `MyType_T`.  (The C++ class is basically a wrapper to the old C code.)  I'd like to be able to pass in a `MyClass*` anywhere I could pass in a `MyType_T*` before.

I'd like to write an automatic conversion of any MyClass* to MyType_T*, but I guess what's throwing me is that my type converter is written to take a `MyClass` not a `MyClass*`.  Even though I'm sure that's the problem, I can't think of what syntax would solve it.  I've thought about making a friend implementation of the cast, but I can't put it before the definition of `class MyClass` because it won't know the offset of `thing`.  And I can't put after the definition of `class MyClass` because the `MyClass` constructor wants to use that conversion.

```
 typedef struct MyStruct {
    int iFoo;
    struct MyType* ptypeParent;
} MyType_T;

void MyTypeCreator( MyType_T* ptypeSelf, int iFoo_in, MyType_T* ptypeParent );

class MyClass {

public:
    MyClass( int iFoo, MyClass* pclassParent ) {

        MyTypeCreator( &thing, iFoo, pclassParent ); <--------------- PROBLEM
        MyTypeCreator( &thing, iFoo, &pclassParent->thing ); <------- WORKS
    };

    operator MyType_T*() { return &thing; } <---------------- INCORRECT: attempts to convert MyClass, not MyClass*, to MyType_T*.

    MyType_T thing;
};
```

QUESTION 1: how to write a convertor from MyClass* instead of MyClass?

QUESTION 2: how can such a convertor check for NULL input?  (If thing isn't offset of 0, but say 8, then converting from a NULL pclass without a check would give a value of 0x00000008, not NULL...)

Comment: Instead of having a member of `MyType_T`, have `MyClass` publicly derive from `MyType_T`. Then `MyClass*` pointer would be implicitly convertible to `MyType_T*` pointer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik good idea and I will consider!  That said I'm curious about this point of C++.

Comment: There's no way in C++ to make a pointer of one type implicitly convertible to a different unrelated pointer type.